System.Exception: 'Unknown column 'm.User_id' in 'on clause''
When I want to retrieve data from the Managers table in my database, I get an error:

System.Exception: 'Unknown column 'm.User_id' in 'on clause'

I'm developing .Net Maui with a MySql database. The database is already existing. EF Core is used to handle database interaction in the app.
Error log:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Error: Failed executing DbCommand (22ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT `u`.`User_id`, `u`.`CreatedAt`, `u`.`First_name`, `u`.`Last_name`, `m`.`Manager_id`
FROM `Users` AS `u`
INNER JOIN `Managers` AS `m` ON `u`.`User_id` = `m`.`User_id`
'WaiterEval.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.4\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WaiterEval.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.4\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WaiterEval.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.4\System.IO.Compression.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query: Error: An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'WaiterEval.Services.MyDbContext'.
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'm.User_id' in 'on clause'

Manager.cs:
[Table("Managers")]
public class Manager : User
{
    public Manager(string First_name, string Last_name, DateTime CreatedAt) : base(First_name, Last_name) { }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int Manager_id
    {
        get => User_id;
        set => User_id = value;
    }
    public User User { get; set; }

}
User.cs:
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] // Auto-incremented primary key
    public int User_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "char(100)")]
    public string First_name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "char(100)")]
    public string Last_name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.Date; // Automatically generated date

}
MyDbContext.cs:
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    // DbSet properties for your database entities
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Manager> Managers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Manager>()
          .HasOne(m => m.User)
          .WithMany()
          .HasForeignKey(m => m.Manager_id);

     }
}

My database was created with this query:
CREATE TABLE Users 
(
    User_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    First_name CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Last_name CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CreatedAt DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE),
    PRIMARY KEY (User_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Managers 
(
    Manager_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Manager_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (Manager_id) REFERENCES Users(User_id)
);

I don't understand why EF Core is looking for a column in user_id in Managers.
I tried TPT, TPH. With and without navigation properties, different OnModelCreating() approaches. Nothing changed the result.

The error is very clear.  I don't see a column User_Id in your Manager table.

Why is Managers a separate table? That's an elaborate way of expressing that you have a User of type "Manager". A Type property/field would suffice.

Your manager class is extending User so you are confusing EF. If a Manager is a separate entity/table that relates to a User then don't inherit User:
public class Manager
{
    [Key]
    public int Manager_id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User_id")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

If manager should extend a user then get rid of the User navigation property and relationship. The Manager table should have a User_id as it's PK and EF set up with a Table-per-Concrete inheritance configuration set to have a separate User and Manager table.
